# Strange behavior of the reputation tab

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, daily-reputation-limit

I recently removed an answer of mine which I posted a few days ago.

On the day of posting the answer it gained several votes, but I also gained more than that amount of votes when I capped out. So deleting this answer should not have any implication on the reputation.

I deleted the answer today, and indeed there were no implication to the actual reputation (I verified it on the /reputation page as well), but the reputation tab shows (at least on my user, I logged out, and it seems fine) as if all my reputation from today is gone. Which doesn't make any sense.

(I am tagging this [support](/questions/tagged/support) rather than [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because I have a feeling that this is by design, although it seems like a faulty logic. If it is indeed a bug, feel free to retag it.)

---

In the meantime, I have undeleted my answer, but here is another strange - oh so very strange - bug. As noted in another thread, a certain *very* high rep. user was serially upvoted (in fact, I was upvoted as well). Now the voting script has reversed the votes, here is what I think is the strangest reputation screen I've seen so far:

[image: Reputation bug]

The keen observer will notice that yesterday this user had only one accepted answer. This means 215 points would be the maximum (which is clearly achieved), but the reputation page shows 345(!!) points, with 130 of them removed the next day.

On the other hand, my page doesn't show this sort of behavior at all, and I don't even know how many upvotes were reversed (using badge count, I estimate five).

Comment: I just viewed [Daniel Fischer's reputation tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer?tab=reputation) incidentally and found something strange. Then I searched in the meta to see if there is any reasonable explanation, and it led me to your post. Firstly, there are successive serial upvotings on Daniel Fischer's answers since Jul 29. Secondly, and more strangely, the serial upvotings on Aug 2 neither generated any reputation nor were shown reversed, but there was a reversal record on Aug 3, correspondingly, no reputation deduction. Did you ever see similar things before?

Comment: Yes. It means the serial voting was during a cap day.

Comment: Dear Asaf Karagila, thank you for your reply. Sorry for my English, I cannot understand what 'a cap day' means.

Comment: There's a daily limit on reputation you can get from votes. It's called a "Cap". Any extra vote is uncounted. When votes are removed, the calculation takes into considering these extra votes, so reputation may be preserved.

Comment: Dear Asaf Karagila, thank you for your patience. It sounds clear to me now.